# Why do projectors use VGA rather than something digital?

Tags: netbook, projector

I'm shopping for a netbook to use for PowerPoint presentations while traveling.  Many netbooks have VGA connectors for hooking up to projectors.  Why do projectors still use VGA?  Does HDMI make sense?  Should I get a netbook with HDMI?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic. If you remove the shopping, you're left with the subjective/argumentative part

Answer (score 2):

Because it's practically ubiquitous. And for the few situations where you don't have a VGA output, there's probably an adapter for it somewhere. Whereas if you have a projector that only has DVI-D or HDMI input, you're pooched if you only have a VGA output.

Comment: There are converters that will do vga to dvi and vga to hdmi, as well as the other way around, it makes no difference.

Comment: @MaQleod: I don't see the difference between providing a presenter with an adapter instead of providing them with the correct interface in the first place. Except for the increased part count, of course.

Comment: Ideally, you would want the correct interface (fewer points of failure is always best). Also ideally you would want the highest grade connection. If an adapter would always be a possible solution, choose the highest grade connection for your side and adapt when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Most projectors these days will have HDMI, VGA and sometimes component or composite inputs. There are also adapters that will handle conversions between pretty much any type of video signal. Considering that the world is moving away from vga and most devices now support HDMI, I would go with the most up to date option.